# jQuery Mobile: Issue with empty option in Select Menu (drop down list)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have implenmented **drop-down lists** "**Select menus**" in ***`jQuery Mobile.`***

```
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="name" class="select ui-select" style ="vertical-align:baseline; width:33%; " ><b>Application:</b></label>
          <select name="select_choice" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-hover-c" id="editWSAppType" >

          <option value="EmptyOption">"  "</option> <!--EMPTY OPTION-->
          <option value="Other">Other</option>
          <option value="Other2">Other2</option>
          <option value="Other3">Other 3</option>


          </select>
    </div>
```

ALL THE OPTIONS ARE SHOWN IN DROP DOWN LIST but there is an issue of alignment of label.

I have used **`vertical-align:baseline`** for now. And I tried other alignment attributes also.

But **in case of EMPTY OPTION the position of label is changed to down when compared to the other options**.

So many select menus in my application are having the same problem.

Some select menus doen't have any opstrong texttions these are also having the same issue.

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <label for="name" class="select ui-select" style ="vertical-align:baseline; width:33%; " ><b>Application:</b></label>
      <select name="select_choice" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-hover-c" id="editWSAppType" >
           <!--NO OPTIONS-->
      </select>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `for` attribute of your label you should put in the the `id` of your select (you currently have `"name"`)

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="editWSAppType" class="select ui-select"  ><b>Application:</b></label>
          <select  name="select_choice" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-hover-c" id="editWSAppType" >

          <option value="EmptyOption"></option> <!--EMPTY OPTION-->
          <option value="Other">Other</option>
          <option value="Other2">Other2</option>
          <option value="Other3">Other 3</option>


          </select>
    </div>
```